# universal set in alloy

Tags: alloy

if I have a set of certain sig e.g. I formulate a set of closed_Switches. Can I get a set of open_switches (or all the switches that are not closed)  as following

```
some x:Switch |  x = (univ - closed_switches)  =>  "and then imply something on x"
```

Just started using alloy,  is this a correct way of approaching this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the set of all open switches, then use the expression containing

```
Switch - closed_switches
```

which you could give a name to:

```
let open_switches = Switch - closed_switches | ...stuff about open_switches...
```

If you want to work with one open switch then something like:

```
some x : Switch - closed_switches | ...stuff about x...
```